# Does this probability make sense: p(x)p(x|a)?

Tags: probability

Let's say x is some event occurring, $p(x)$ is the probability of x occurring, and $p(x|a)$ is the probability of event x occurring given event a has occured. Does this probability make any sense, and if so what does it mean?

$p(x)p(x|a)$

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense.  In general, the product $p(x) \cdot p(x|a)$ will not sum to one over the allowable values of $x$, so it is not a "probability".

Answer (score 3):

As also pointed out in the comment, it doesn't make sense even if you try to read it: The probability of $X$ *happened* times the probability of $X$ *happened given* that $A$ *happened*. When do we multiply the probabilities, anyway? A typical case is when we want events to happen at the same time/together. For example, we could read the typical multiplication $P(X)P(A|X)$ as *probability of X happens and given that it happens we also want A happens*. It follows a logical chain.

Comment: Thanks, I just have a follow-up question. Is there a way to interpret the following probability: $\frac{p(x|a)}{p(x)}$.

Comment: Sorry how did you arrive at that? Shouldn't it be $p(x,a)/p(x)p(a)$ from bayes law?

Comment: I think it might be interpreted as a measure of the effect of event  on the occurrence of event , because if  increases/decreases the chance of event , the ratio will be greater/less than 1. If it is 1, the events are independent. And, as you can see it's not a probability.